# link header to homepage (for wp multisite)

Tags: links, headers

I am using the genesis framework and have added this code to change the way genesis uploads a header image:

```
remove_action( 'wp_head', 'genesis_custom_header_style' );
add_action( 'genesis_header', 'andym_header' );
function andym_header() {
echo '<img src="'.get_header_image().'">';
}
```

This code just puts the header image in the html instead as a css background.

I would also like to link the header to user homepages like the h1 site title links to homepages.

I tried changing the header function in the code above to:

```
function andym_main_header() {
echo '<a href="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>">  <img src="'.get_header_image().'"></a>';
```

}

but got a syntax error, unexpected T_STRING, expecting ‘,’ or ‘;’

I don't know php very well, any help appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few issues- php tags are for interpolating between php/html, they can't go within php statements. Also, the single quotes in `bloginfo` are closing your string, which is generating the error. Lastly, `bloginfo` will `echo` its value, which can't go within an `echo` statement, you need to use `get_bloginfo` instead, or simpler, just use `home_url()`:

```
echo '<a href="' . home_url() . '"><img src="' . get_header_image() . '"></a>';
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked. I got the bloginfo snippet from http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/bloginfo where bloginfo is anchoring the site title, thought I might be able to do something similar. Thanks for your reply

Comment: This was my first question on here, didn't know you were supposed to accept answers back then. Accepted :)